# Codeigniter Redirect Loop for user session is logged in

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

**My controller**

```
class Backspaze extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        session_start();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('getDB');
        $this->IsLogged();
}

function IsLogged()
    {
        if (!$this->session->userdata('id'))
            {
                 header('Location: '.base_url().'login');
         }

    }


function Login()
{


    $this->load->view('Auth/Login');
}

}
```

**.htaccess**

```
  RewriteBase /backspaze
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I almost tried all things which is available in internet the page gets redirect loop while checking for user is logged in, please give me some solutions

MY Config
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the following points

- In your case, You should not check the session in `constructor`
  level. , Means, your controller consists of public & authenticated
  pages. So it will be looping/redirecting inside this
  controller only.
- Move the session checking condition to the specific page and redirect
  to `login` page if suppose no session for authenticated pages. Below
  I have checked for `user_details` page which is I created for your
  understanding.
- In your login method, you should check the `already logged in or not`
  and if yes, it should be go to `dashboard` page. I have created one
  method for that `IsAlreadyLogged`. please check it.
- Don't add `session_start()` in your controller which will be take
  care of CI core
- Use build-in `redirect` method which is CI core has
- You should check session in constructor level if all pages are need
  to be authenticated in controller.

.

```
class Backspaze extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('getDB');
    }

    function IsLogged()
    {
        if (!$this->session->userdata('id'))
        {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }

    function IsAlreadyLogged()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('id'))
        {
            redirect('dashboard');
        }
    }

    function user_details()
    {
        $this->IsLogged();
        $this->load->view('user/details');
    }


    function Login()
    {
        $this->IsAlreadyLogged();
        $this->load->view('Auth/Login');
    }

}
```

Comment: checking session at construct is not wrong.even it is better instead of checking session at all method.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam, Depeds upon the controller...if some of the page is public in that controller, we should not check the session in constructor..

Comment: Ashik in ur case it will not check for all pages whether the person is logged in or not, i got the point of what you saying but incase by leaving public pages and to check login for only protected pages whether i need to check in each functions or i need to open a separate controller

Comment: You should check session in constructor level if all pages are need to be authenticated in controller.

Answer (score 0):

remove the line

```
session_start();
```

codeigniter handle it itself.
Replace this

```
header('Location: '.base_url().'login');
```

with

```
  redirect(base_url()."login");`
```

but make sure you have loaded url helper

Comment: i have done this but still redirect loop and i loaded the helper class too