# Redirect loop in Codeigniter with single redirect from base controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-routing

I have this base controller:

```
class TCMS_Controller extends  CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if( ! $this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('admin/authenticate/login');
        }
        //Loop to get all settings in the "globals" table
        foreach($this->Settings_model->get_global_settings() as $result){
            $this->global_data[$result->key] = $result->value;
        }
    }
}
```

So there I have this basic redirect:

`redirect('admin/authenticate/login');` if user is not logged in.

Also I have this settings to remove `index.php` from urls:

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And next config settings:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://something.herokuapp.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And when I'm trying to access admin section that has next address:

```
http://something.herokuapp.com/admin/controller/method
```

And if I'm not logged in, I supposed to be redirected to `login` page:

```
http://something.herokuapp.com/admin/authenticate/login
```

But instead i get a redirect loop

`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

How do I fix it?

The page:
http://tcms.herokuapp.com/

The admin section: http://tcms.herokuapp.com/admin/authenticate/login
http://tcms.herokuapp.com/admin/dashobard

Comment: Please check your browser console to see what the page is actually trying to redirect to.

Comment: can you show your refresh url link?

Comment: added links to website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure your `admin`(may be `authenticate` if admin is your folder name) controller also extends `TCMS_Controller`. So when it redirects your `admin` controller it executes `TCMS_Controller`'s construct function again and again redirect to admin controller which cause infinite loop.

To sovle this you need to make a `Login` controller which does not extends `TCMS_Controller` just extends  CI_Controller.And redirect to this controller if user is not loged-in.

Comment: admin is a subfolder in my controllers folder with all admin-related controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem that it's bad practice to have redirects in basic controller, because it can cause redirecting loops:

See: [Codeigniter Redirect Loop for user session is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979319/codeigniter-redirect-loop-for-user-session-is-logged-in)